# how to make different section with responsive behaviour in html

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hi i'm a very new designer trying to learn designing

**problems pointed by my boss:**

1. my boss told your layout is semantically is not correct
2. lines are not aligned  correctly
3. not responsive

**he advised me:**

1. convert it to `flexbox` as content will come dynamically, `flexbox` wll handle
2. make it such a responsive such that based on `content` responsiveness should be preserved

**problems image:**

[image]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    /* font-size: 62.5%; */
}

body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #A7A7A7;
}
header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav{
    /* background: grey; */
    border-bottom:2px solid #E4E4E4;
    display:block;
    /* display:table; */
    width: 100%;
}

header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li{
   padding: 6px;
   border-right:1px solid #E4E4E4;
   position: relative;
   display:table-cell;
}
header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li.active-nav{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F89106;
}

#content_wrapper_search_etl{
    width: 100%;
}

#content_wrapper_search_etl::after{
    content:'';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

section{
    display: block;
}

.leftside-search-area{
    width: 13%;
    float: left;
    height: 98vh;
    /* background: green; */
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4; 
}
.leftside-search-area input{
  border-left: none !important;
}

.center-search-area{
    width: 27%;
    float: left;
    height: 98vh;
    /* background: yellow; */
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.right-search-area{
    width: 49.3%;
    float: left;
    height: 98vh;
    /* background: orangered; */
}
.right-search-area input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome */
    color:#FE8D51;
}
.center-search-area input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome */
    color: #A1A1A1;
}
.right-search-area input,.center-search-area input,.leftside-search-area input{
    width: 101%;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-top: none;
    height: 25px;
    border-right: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}

.vertical-box .box{
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.vertical-box .box h4{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.vertical-box .box .tags ul{
   list-style: none;
}

.vertical-box .box .tags ul li{
   display: block;
   padding: 6px;
   background: #E5E5E7;
   margin-top: 19px;
 }

 .vertical-box .box .tags ul li.square{
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 3px;
  }

.vertical-box .box .tags ul li.round{
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 4px 34px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.vertical-box .box .tags ul li.tag-active{
    background: #FB8D58;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main_container_blz">
      <header class="main-header">
          <nav class="main-navigation">
             <ul class="nav">
                 <li class="active-nav"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</li>
                 <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Users</li>
                 <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
     <div id="content_wrapper_search_etl">
         <section class="leftside-search-area">
             <input type="search" placeholder="&#xf0b0; FILTER">
             <div class="vertical-box">
                 <div class="box">
                    <h4>File Types</h4>
                    <div class="tags">
                       <ul>
                           <li class="square tag-active"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                           </li>
                           <li class="square"><i class="fa fa-music"></i>                           </li>
                           <li class="square"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>                           </li> 
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="box">
                   <h4>Date</h4>
                   <div class="tags">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="round tag-active">Today</li>
                            <li class="round">Yesterday</li>
                            <li class="round">Last week</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="box">
                     <h4>Status</h4>
                     <div class="tags">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="round">Today</li>
                            <li class="round">Today</li>
                            <li class="round">Today</li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </section>
         <section class="center-search-area">
                <input type="search" placeholder="&#xf002;    Search...">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, reiciendis. Officiis necessitatibus maiores labore quaerat ea eum maxime, ratione ut fugit in voluptatibus. Cum amet perspiciatis, quasi quae illum labore?</p>
         </section>
         <section class="right-search-area">
                <input type="search" placeholder="&#xf007;  Dhobi">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Animi ipsum, saepe deleniti modi expedita minus amet doloribus impedit rem deserunt neque necessitatibus sequi nisi facilis harum tempora quae voluptate voluptatibus.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi suscipit est modi exercitationem ipsum eaque, laborum iure hic nobis adipisci, magnam alias sit maxime repellat commodi quam! Numquam, repudiandae?</p>
         </section>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**here is full code (codepen):**https://codepen.io/eabangalore/details/NLLRPv/ (please change view to editor and fork it)

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at flex box and try to understand first https://css-tricks.com/designing-a-product-page-layout-with-flexbox/

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, here snippet does not work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fair bit to work through here. I'll go through in order as they appear in your image.

### Realigning the navigation underline

The top border of the element below the selected navigation has a thickness of 2px. You need your selected navigation item's underline to cover that border. Your current method of underlining the selected nav item is using `border-bottom` which isn't able to overlap in the way you need. Use the `::after` pseudo element instead.

```
header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li.active-nav::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px; /* same thickness as your original border */
    background: #F89106;
    bottom: -2px; /* places it exactly over the below element's top border */
    left: 0;
}
```

---

### Displaying as flex

To display as flex is as simple as setting the parent to `display: flex;` and removing the `float: left;` from its children. You've set the width of each child individually, which doesn't necessarily need to change, but as you say above it's better to let flexbox work out the widths. I took out all the widths, which makes your Search and Dhobi panels as wide as each other.

Additionally I think you may find `min-height` better than `height`; when you use `height` your content in the Filter panel is overflowing and thus the panel borders don't extend to the bottom of the page.

```
#content_wrapper_search_etl{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /* key element */
}
.leftside-search-area{ /* no float and no width, same with the other panels */
    min-height: 98vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4; 
}
.center-search-area{
    min-height: 98vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.right-search-area{
    min-height: 98vh;
}
```

---

### Correctly aligning input borders

Your input was slightly too wide with some interesting border parameters that made it appear to be unaligned with the rest of the vertical borders. Make the input width 100% and set all borders to `none` except `border-bottom`. This also fixes a problem with flex overflowing.

```
.right-search-area input,.center-search-area input,.leftside-search-area input{
    width: 100%; /* not 101% */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4; /* set border-bottom only */
    height: 25px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
```

---

### (somewhat) Responsive overflow

To stop the elements in your Filter panel overflowing you could either set the `min-width` property, or you could do it in a flexboxy way with `align-self: flex-start;` However this can make some of your label text wrap within the label. To fix that set your labels' `white-space: nowrap;`. Finally you need to add some horizontal padding to space it out a little from the edge.

A suggestion: you may want to try `flex-direction: column;` in your `.box` CSS.

This isn't true responsiveness but it solves the overflow problem.

```
.leftside-search-area{
    align-self: flex-start; /* keep width to that of its content */
    min-height: 98vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.vertical-box .box{
    white-space: nowrap; /* prevent labels wrapping */
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px; /* space from horizontal edges */
    ...
}
```

---

A pen forked from yours that implements all of the above is found at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMqVVq

The result:

[image: Result]

Hopefully this addresses all the display issues you're having.

Answer (score 1):

#### Improving the responsiveness

> I would suggest using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to fix your responsiveness
>   issues.

Simply add `display: grid` to your content wrapper and specify the template size of each columns e.g:

```
#content_wrapper_search_etl{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content .5fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and remove the `width`s of your search areas: `.leftside-search-area`, `.center-search-area` and `.right-search-area`.

#### Fixing the border alignments

Set the `width` to `100%` and not `101%` in your search `input`s. Keep the `border: none;` and only set the `border-bottom` property to fix the border alignments:

```
.right-search-area input,.center-search-area input,.leftside-search-area input{
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    ...
}
```

#### Fixing the active `nav` underline

Remove the current style:

```
header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li.active-nav{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F89106;
}
```

and use a pseudo element instead e.g `::before`:

```
header.main-header .main-navigation ul.nav li.active-nav::before {
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F89106;
}
```

> Forked pen: https://codepen.io/knekk/pen/pOQxrQ?editors=1100